# adding a shell for git command when commit

Tags: git

is it possible or is there a tool, so I could add a piece of text for every commit comment, like this:

```
A
B: 1
C: xxx
```

to achieve the following comment layout, that I only need to input XXXX? (the cursor stops next to `C:`) for every `git commit`.

[image]

Comment: You could create your own script that adds the message. Let's call it commit-with-message. You run ./commit-with-message (for example) "my message" and it will behave like git commit -m or stuff like that. However, is not so useful unless you chain commands.

Comment: @AndreiToader I found the duplicate url is interesting. But I am not sure I could use it with mingw git

Comment: Then use `commit.template`.